# Не запускается приложение на heroku

Tags: java, telegram-bot, heroku

Создал telegram bot'a на java. Теперь пытаюсь задеплоить его в heroku. Выходит ошибка, лог:

```
2017-10-01T16:47:04.211642+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-10-01T16:47:07.495272+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `java -cp target/classes/:target/dependency/* com.mycompany.telegrambotmaven.telegrambot`
2017-10-01T16:47:08.134088+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-10-01T16:47:11.072297+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-10-01T16:47:11.084848+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2017-10-01T16:47:10.765250+00:00 app[worker.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
2017-10-01T16:47:10.937940+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class com.mycompany.telegrambotmaven.TelegramBot
```

Procfile:

```
worker: java -cp target/classes/:target/dependency/* com.mycompany.telegrambotmaven.TelegramBot
```

Comment: Где main class?

Comment: В файле target/classes/com/mycompany/telegrambotmaven/TelegramBot.class
Код находится там: src/main/java/com/mycompany/telegrambotmaven/TelegramBot.java

Comment: Почему регистр неправильный?

Comment: Здесь неправильно написал. Исправил.

Comment: Вот и запиши в `Procfile` c правильным регистром.

Comment: Там правильно написано. Только здесь было неправильно

Comment: Ты логи вручную писал?

Comment: Нет. Скопировал.

Comment: https://github.com/piller1997/rsreubot Вот проект